# How to configure Apache2 with Laravel Backend/React Frontend

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, apache2

I'm attempting to setup a server configuration where React is the frontend and Laravel is the API, but I'm unsure of how to setup Apache2 so that mydomain.com/api will serve Laravel and everything else will serve React

I tried setting up a separate site config file for Laravel at mydomain.com/api being routed to the Laravel public folder but it doesn't work

Any advice is appreciated

Thanks

- Zach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this before and fixed it as below.

I did not create a new configuration file for the second site, just included it as Alias as below.

in your 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Alias /api/ /var/www/html/api
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Alias defines your new site or application.

When you are setting up the Alias, if "/api/" does not work, try /api. either one of them should work.

And make sure, you set your document root configurations in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Couldn't find it *ANYWHERE* online

Comment: Thanks, it works, it worked for me using this form "/api" BTW